# Linux run kernel probe systemtap script failed with semantic error: no match"

Tags: linux, kernel, systemtap

I've got 2 experimental environment: CentOS 6.8 and Ubuntu 16.04  Both run inside Virtualbox VM.

On CentOS I installed

```
yum install kernel-devel kernel-debug
```

On Ubuntu I installed:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install fakeroot build-essential crash kexec-tools makedumpfile kernel-wedge
```

On both systems I can run this successfully:

```
stap -ve 'probe begin { log("hello world") exit() }'
```

I tried this `.stp` script from *systemtap* guide:

```
#!/usr/bin/stap
probe begin
{
    log("begin probe")
}
probe syscall.open
{
    printf("%s(%d) open (%s)\n",execname(),pid(),argstr)
}
probe timer.ms(4000)#4s later
{
    exit()
}
probe end
{
    log("end probe")
}
```

`chmod +x ...` the script and run as `root` user.  Both systems report errors like:

```
./test2.stp -v
Pass 1: parsed user script and 124 library script(s) using 217780virt/45168res/3204shr/42664data kb, in 210usr/20sys/238real ms.
semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'kernel' at /usr/share/systemtap/tapset/linux/syscalls2.stp:197:24
        source: probe __syscall.open = kernel.function("sys_open").call
                                       ^

semantic error: missing x86_64 kernel/module debuginfo [man warning::debuginfo] under '/lib/modules/2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64/build'

semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier '__syscall' at :177:47
        source: probe syscall.open = __syscall.compat_open ?, __syscall.open
                                                              ^

semantic error: no match

semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'syscall' at ./test2.stp:6:7
        source: probe syscall.open
                      ^

semantic error: no match

Pass 2: analyzed script: 3 probe(s), 6 function(s), 0 embed(s), 0 global(s) using 230172virt/57516res/5204shr/52952data kb, in 120usr/150sys/270real ms.
Pass 2: analysis failed.  [man error::pass2]
```

What's this error about?  Is it an installation problem?  Is there a syntax error in my script?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr** install kernel image debug symbols, e.g. package `linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym`.

### Problem Background

I was having similar error

```
$ sudo stap -v udp_detect_exec.stp
...
semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'kernel' at /usr/share/systemtap/tapset/linux/udp.stp:39:21
        source: probe udp.sendmsg = kernel.function("udp_sendmsg") {
```

From a `systemtap` script to [track DNS requests](https://serverfault.com/a/683327/116615)

```
#! /usr/bin/env stap
probe udp.sendmsg {
  if ( dport == 53 && ( daddr == "8.8.8.8" || daddr == "8.8.4.4" ) ) {
    printf ("PID %5d (%s) sent UDP to %15s 53\n", pid(), execname(), daddr)
  }
}
```

Following [this blog.jeffli.me post](https://blog.jeffli.me/blog/2014/10/10/install-systemtap-in-ubuntu-14-dot-04/), a *hello world* `systemtap` script worked.

```
sudo stap -e 'probe kernel.function("sys_open") {log("hello world") exit()}'
```

### Solution (install kernel debug symbols)

Following this [wiki.ubuntu.com entry](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Systemtap#Where_to_get_debug_symbols_for_kernel_X.3F), my *Ubuntu 16.04* system was missing the kernel debug symbols.  I ran install steps:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C8CAB6595FDFF622
codename=$(lsb_release -c | awk  '{print $2}')
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list << EOF
  deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ ${codename}      main restricted universe multiverse
  deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ ${codename}-security main restricted universe multiverse
  deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ ${codename}-updates  main restricted universe multiverse
  deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ ${codename}-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
EOF
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym
```

The script `udp_detect_exec.stp` successfully ran.

I recommended checking for updated `apt-get install` steps at the *wiki.ubuntu.com* entry.