# Kernel Installation error: failed to write (No space left on device)

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, systemtap, debug-information

I am installing SystemTap on linux server. When I run the test script: `sudo stap -v -e 'probe vfs.read {printf("read performed"); exit()}'` I got the below error message.

```
Pass 1: parsed user script and 480 library scripts using 107788virt/78136res/5648shr/72936data kb, in 170usr/10sys/194real ms.
semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'kernel' at /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/linux/vfs.stp:980:18
        source: probe vfs.read = kernel.function("vfs_read")
                                 ^

semantic error: missing x86_64 kernel/module debuginfo [man warning::debuginfo] under '/lib/modules/4.15.0-137-generic/build'

semantic error: resolution failed in alias expansion builder

semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'vfs' at <input>:1:7
        source: probe vfs.read {printf("read performed"); exit()}
                      ^

semantic error: no match

Pass 2: analyzed script: 0 probes, 0 functions, 0 embeds, 0 globals using 109504virt/80752res/6468shr/74652data kb, in 50usr/60sys/127real ms.
Pass 2: analysis failed.  [man error::pass2]
```

I found this useful link [Linux run kernel probe systemtap script failed with semantic error: no match"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42975553/linux-run-kernel-probe-systemtap-script-failed-with-semantic-error-no-match) , that suggest me to download the corresponding

- kernel-debuginfo-common-`uname -r`
- kernel-debuginfo-`uname -r`

---

Since the kernel version I have is 4.15.0-137-generic, I found the required kernel package here, http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/
However, when I build it with `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-137-generic-dbgsym_4.15.0-137.141_amd64.ddeb`

```
dpkg: error processing archive linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-137-generic-dbgsym_4.15.0-137.141_amd64.ddeb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/4.15.0-137-generic/kernel/drivers/media/rc/fintek-cir.ko' to '/usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/4.15.0-137-generic/kernel/drivers/media/rc/fintek-cir.ko.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-137-generic-dbgsym_4.15.0-137.141_amd64.ddeb
```

Comment: Are you running CentOS?

Comment: Stating the bleedin' obvious, it looks like it ran out of disk space.