# SystemTap semantic error when trying to run dvorak-qwerty script

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, debug-symbols, systemtap, dvorak, qwerty

I found [this repo](https://github.com/kentonv/dvorak-qwerty/blob/master/unix/dvorak-qwerty.stp) with a systemtap script for letting me use QWERTY ctrl-shortcuts on my dvorak layout. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work, but I don't think it has to do with the script itself. I'm running Pop OS and I think that it's because the linux-image I need with all the debug symbols doesn't exist.

The script says I need to install `linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbg`
For me, this turns into `linux-headers-5.11.0-7620-generic linux-image-5.11.0-7620-generic-dbg`

`linux-headers-5.11.0-7620-generic` exists and I'm able to download it using apt-get.
`linux-image-5.11.0-7620-generic-dbg` can't be installed using apt-get. I can install
`linux-image-5.11.0-7620-generic`, but that's not the same thing. I've spent time looking online for it and adding different keys to apt-get, but I haven't been able to find anything with that name. If the problem is not having the correct linux-image package installed, I need help being pointed in the right direction as to where I can get it.

I tried following the directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42975553/linux-run-kernel-probe-systemtap-script-failed-with-semantic-error-no-match), and I've also searched [this](http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/) to no avail. I tried downloading and installing `linux-image-4.4.0-142-generic-dbgsym_4.4.0-142.168_amd64.ddeb` but that also didn't work.

If this isn't the problem, I've provided the output of the script. Any help is appreciated.

```
peyton@pop-os:~/scripts$ sudo stap -g -v dvorak-qwerty.stp
Pass 1: parsed user script and 477 library scripts using 116428virt/91336res/7612shr/83628data kb, in 140usr/30sys/168real ms.
semantic error: resolution failed in DWARF builder

semantic error: resolution failed in DWARF builder

semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'module' at dvorak-qwerty.stp:152:7
        source: probe module("evdev").function("evdev_events") {
                      ^

semantic error: no match

semantic error: resolution failed in DWARF builder

Pass 2: analyzed script: 2 probes, 0 functions, 1 embed, 0 globals using 119016virt/94812res/8680shr/86216data kb, in 10usr/0sys/7real ms.
Pass 2: analysis failed.  [man error::pass2]
Tip: /usr/share/doc/systemtap/README.Debian should help you get started.
```

Comment: so I went to this link: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Systemtap#How_do_I_build_a_debuginfo_kernel_if_one_isn.27t_available.3F
And followed the instructions to create my own linux image dbg file. Once I got it installed, system tap is still unable to find the module function in the script I'm trying to run.
This command doesn't work: `stap -l 'module("ohci1394").function("*")' | sort`
This command does work: `stap -L 'module("thinkpad_acpi").function("brightness*")' | sort`
This command, the one in the scrip, doesn't work: `module("evdev").function("evdev_events")`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Same question on askubuntu.com https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400702/dvorak-qwerty-systemtap-fails  I did get this to work though https://github.com/tbocek/dvorak

Answer (score 0):

Yes, debuginfo downloading has been a pain on many distros.  However, if you're running Debian kernels, see: https://wiki.debian.org/Debuginfod for instructions on using a new automated system.  Generally: https://sourceware.org/elfutils/Debuginfod.html .