# How do I install kernel debug symbols on Amazon Linux AMI?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, gdb, kernel, systemtap

I'm trying to use System Tap for gdb-helpers (an extension of the C debugger gdb), but I get an error that I've found on Stack to be caused by not having the kernel debug symbols installed (see here: [Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42975553/linux-run-kernel-probe-systemtap-script-failed-with-semantic-error-no-match)).

My problem is, I've only found the installation instructions for Ubuntu and CentOS, and I'm on Amazon Linux AMI version 2018.03.

I've Googled to hell and back, and NOWHERE can I find the yum to install the kernel debug symbols for Amazon.

Does anyone know how to do this and fix my issue?

Comment: The first thing I'd try is the [stap-prep](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stap-prep.1.html) command. Did your systemtap installation provide a copy of this?

Comment: I ran stap-prep and it appeared to install the amazon kernel debug symbols, but I still get the python error:

`semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'kernel' at /home/zach/gdb-helpers-master/gdbhelpers/preattach.stp:17:7
        source: probe kernel.trace("signal_deliver") {`

It complains about the kernel.